# Constructing the same object over and over again

Tags: c++, object, vector

I just learned C++ and while I was practicing I came across the situation where I wanted to reset all my vector array's values back to zero. I was wondering what actually happens to vectorArr if you keep doing this:

```
i = 0;
while(i < 5)
{
    vector<int> vectorArr(some_size); 
    ...
    i++; 
}
```

Does it just discard the previous one from memory and makes a new one with the same name?

Comment: Yes, C++ uses [scopes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) for lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vectorArr only appears on the while scope, so after reach the end of the loop, vectorArr destroyed, when start again, it is a brand new vector.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will create and destroy vectorArr every time as braces{} decide lifetime of object so to avoid creation and deletion every time you can do like below :

```
i = 0;
vector<int> vectorArr(some_size); 
while(i < 5)
{ 
    ...
    i++; 
    vectorArr.clear(); //last statement of while loop
}
```